# Cookies (as JWT) not storing in any browser and a weird URL error is comming in the console

Tags: reactjs, cookies, proxy, jwt, mern

I made a sign-in and sign-out based react app. Everything is working fine except for one thing. the browser is not storing any cookies (even though server is setting the cookie correctly as POSTMAN indeed show the cookie and its value in the response) and a weird error is also occuring (mentioned below the code). Here are the relevant sections of my code:

// The SignIn Component

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignIn() {
    const Navigate = useNavigate();

    const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });

    function handleChange(e) {
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, password } = user;

        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        });

        const data = await res.json();

        if (res.status === 422 || !data) {
            alert(data.error);
        } else {
            alert(data.message);
            Navigate('/about');
        }
    }

    return (
        <>      
        // the rest of JSX of signin UI component
        </>
    );
}
export default SignIn;
```

// The Routes (server)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const auth = require('../auth');
const MernUser = require('../../Database/Models/mernUserSchema_1');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const cors = require('cors');

router.use(cors());
router.use(cookieParser());
router.use(express.json());

router.post('/signin', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if (!email || !password) return res.status(422).json({ error: 'Please fill all the details' });

        const existingUser = await MernUser.findOne({ email });

        if (existingUser) {
            const matched = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);

            if (matched) {
                const token = await existingUser.genAuthToken(); // This function is working fine

                res.cookie('jwt', token); // This is not working for some reason

                return res.status(200).json({ message: 'login successful' });
            } else return res.status(422).json({ error: 'Invalid P login Details' });
        } else return res.status(422).json({ error: 'Invalid login Details' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Error: inject.js:1     GET http://localhost:5173/giompennnhheakjcnobejbnjgbbkmdnd-proxy.html 404 (Not Found)

The above error is not stopping the program to work. The program stores user data and verify it correctly but just can not store any cookie (not sure if the above error is related to this cookies problem).I have tried other stack overflow solutions but I am not being able to get this working.
Also, I have checked POSTMAN and it indeed show the cookie and its value but still any browser is not showing that !!
Please forgive any code Optimization mistakes as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow credentials from your node server:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
//...
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // this line
//...
});
```

then include it when you send a REQUEST from your React app:

```js
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  credentials: 'include' // this line
});
```

learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) about Access-Control-Allow-Credentials